# How to export a boolean value as "enable"/"disable" in sonata admin export function

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

The field `public` of my entity is boolean. I want to turn this value into `enable` or `disable` in the export file.

```
public function getExportFields()
{
    return [
        'slug',
        'title',
        'collection',
        'type',
        'createdAt',
        'updatedAt',
        'author',
        'state',
        'public' 
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a getter function in your entity class converting your value to string

```
public function isPublicAsString() {
   return $this->isPublic ? 'enable' : 'disable';
}
```

In your export function, replace `public` with `publicAsString`.